# How to get list of all SSID names in ios?

Tags: ios, wifi

I am developing app to get all available wifi stations in Tableview. I get connected SSID name but i want all available SSID names. How can i get all available SSID name?

Comment: you will get only connected ssid name.

Comment: Ya thats true but is that possible to get all ssid names?

Comment: Without the use of private library (Apple80211) you can only get the SSID of the network your device is currently connected to.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem without the private lib?

Comment: There is a bunch of applications in the App Store which could get a list of ssid names(Wi-Fi Finder as example), so it means that is somehow possible to do this. Would be nice if someone could share how do they did it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following link to get the job done.
https://github.com/belkevich/reachability-ios

else try this

```
 @import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork;

/** Returns first non-empty SSID network info dictionary.
 *  @see CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo */
- (NSDictionary *)fetchSSIDInfo
{
NSArray *interfaceNames = CFBridgingRelease(CNCopySupportedInterfaces());
NSLog(@"%s: Supported interfaces: %@", __func__, interfaceNames);

NSDictionary *SSIDInfo;
for (NSString *interfaceName in interfaceNames) {
    SSIDInfo = CFBridgingRelease(
        CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)interfaceName));
    NSLog(@"%s: %@ => %@", __func__, interfaceName, SSIDInfo);

    BOOL isNotEmpty = (SSIDInfo.count > 0);
    if (isNotEmpty) {
        break;
    }
}
return SSIDInfo;
}
```

Comment: this answer will give only connected ssid name not all.